# $http return a status -1, and data: null despite the fact that http proxy is showing a positive respose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, http, ionic-framework

So, I unfortunately I can't post code. I'll try to be as explicit as possible without it.

I'm sending a POST request via Angular's $http. And $http always invokes my error callback with status: -1, data: null.

What's weird is that I can view the request/response in Charles (an http proxy) and the response is coming back as a 200 OK with the xml data I need. Despite that, $http still invokes the error callback.

Additionally, the request works perfectly in PostMan.

The status: -1 is supposedly an aborted request:

> -1 usually means the request was aborted, e.g. using a config.timeout

From: [angular $http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

But I don't know why the request would be aborted. And there's no error messaging at all.

If it helps I'm running this in Ionic, on an iOS emulator (though I have the same issue on an actual iPhone).

Comment: at a guess you have a CORS problem - is the POST request to a different origin to the page?

Comment: yes, it's an external api. Any tips for debugging that without any sort of error messaging?

Comment: unfortunately the problem is with the server not allowing you to access it's resources

Comment: the server is sending me back exactly the response that I need. I can see it in my http proxy. It's just not showing up in my javascript.

Comment: search CORS for all the answers